# Rotate Custom Object in Animation Loop

Tags: loops, canvas, rotation, requestanimationframe

I created some Functions, these will draw Rectangles, Circles, Hexagons etc.
One of them looks like this:

```
rotation = 45;
function hex(hex_sides, hex_size, hex_color){
  x = ctx.canvas.width/2;
  y = ctx.canvas.height/2;

  ctx.save();
  ctx.rotate(rotation*Math.PI/180);
  ctx.translate(ctx.canvas.width/2, ctx.canvas.height/2);
  ctx.moveTo(x + hex_size * Math.cos(0), y + hex_size * Math.sin(0));
  ctx.restore();

  for (i = 0; i < hex_sides+1; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(x + hex_size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / hex_sides), y + hex_size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / hex_sides));
  }

  ctx.strokeStyle = hex_color;
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

Now i call the Functions to Draw the Shapes inside my animation loop.

```
function loop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  circle(200);
  circle(220);
  hex(6, 180, "#fff");
  rotation += 0.4;
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

I'm incrementing the `var rotation` inside the loop but it does not rotate the whole shape but just one line of it instead. Other Shapes i cant get to rotate at all.
I think i got a wrong approach, maybe because of my confusion about .save() and `.restore()` or `.beginPath()` and `.closePath()`.

In General the behaviour is very strange when i start to use `.translate()` and `.rotate()`

> [The entire Code is here.](https://codepen.io/Tibixx/pen/zaxXGN)

**UPDATE**
It is definitely something about this line:

```
ctx.translate(ctx.canvas.width/2, ctx.canvas.height/2);
```

Somehow it does not translate correctly. The rotation now happens around the right middle side of the normal shape position but i want the rotation around its own axis.

I changed the `hex()` function to:

```
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(ctx.canvas.width/2, ctx.canvas.height/2);
ctx.rotate(rotation*Math.PI/180);
ctx.moveTo(x + hex_size * Math.cos(0), y + hex_size * Math.sin(0));
for (i = 0; i < hex_sides+1; i++) {
  ctx.lineTo(x + hex_size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / hex_sides), y + hex_size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / hex_sides));
}
ctx.strokeStyle = hex_color;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();
```

> [Again, entire Code is here.](https://codepen.io/Tibixx/pen/zaxXGN)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... figured it out, i have forgotten to substract half of the shapes width from the translation point and also the order seems to be more important then i tought.

Working Code

```
function hex(hex_sides, hex_size, hex_color){
    x = ctx.canvas.width/2;
    y = ctx.canvas.height/2;

    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(x,y);
    ctx.rotate(rotation*Math.PI/180);
    //ctx.moveTo(x + hex_size * Math.cos(0), y + hex_size * Math.sin(0));
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    for (i = 0; i < hex_sides+1; i++) {
        ctx.lineTo(x/hex_size + hex_size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / hex_sides), y/hex_size + hex_size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / hex_sides));
    }
    ctx.strokeStyle = hex_color;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
}
```